# Typeahead.js - suggestion is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typeahead.js

After long struggles with Twitters typeahead.js, I'm finally at the point where I get to decide which template I should use for my suggestions.

But although this would seem like a straight-forward procedure, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: g.templates.suggestion is not a function

My code looks like this

HTML:

```
<input id = "search" type="text" placeholder="Colors">
```

Javascript:

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];

var colorsource = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
  local: colors
});

$('#search').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'color',
  source: colorsource,
  templates: {
  empty: [
    '<div class="empty-message">',
      'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
    '</div>'
  ].join('\n'),
  suggestion: '<div>{{color}}</div>'
}
});
```

I've seen examples where Handlebars.js is being used to compile the template, but I'm planning on using variables from Angular.js in my suggestions, so I don't want to do that.

Any suggestions on how this problem can be solved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You suggestion options must be a function that returns the HTML, e.g.

```
...
suggestion: function(e) { return ('<div>' + e.value + '</div>'); }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am following @potatopeelings but the suggestions not appear.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#penilai").typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            var countries = [];
            map = {};

            return $.post('/Evaluation/JsonSenaraiPenilai', { query: query }, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                    map[country.Evaluator_name] = country;
                    countries.push(country.Evaluator_name);
                });
                process(countries);
            });
        },
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="empty-message">',
                'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function (e) { return ('<div>' + e.Evaluator_name + '-' + e.Evalator_staf_no + '</div>'); }
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            var selectedShortCode = map[item].Evalator_staf_no;
            $("#evalutor").val(selectedShortCode);
            return item;
        }
    });
});
```